# Why do I need to specify the controller inside rails 3 controller routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

The following route works:

```
controller :foo do 
    get 'bar/:baz' => "foo#bar"
end
```

but this

```
controller :foo do 
    get 'bar/:baz'
end
```

will throw `missing :action`

Why doesn't it detect the action and default to the "foo" controller?

Answer (score 0):

Routing finds a controller and renders a view when finds one. The part `=> "foo#bar"` corresponds to 'goto controller `foo` and render view `bar.html.erb`'.

I haven't tested my statement but will do so later this evening.

Comment: I understand what the `=> "foo#bar"` part does. My question is why is it needed? I already specified controller.